# Regex an enum from MySQL

Tags: php, regex, split

I'm trying to regex a string that comes from a mysql `enum` by using `SHOW COLUMNS FROM Table`. I get the following string and want to parse the words inside it:

```
'Apple','Banana','Other fruit','Pineapple'
```

Should I regex this one, or should I do some string splitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cols = explode("','", substr($str, 1, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just split and trim:

```
$trim_quotes = function($value) {
    return trim($value, " '");
}
$names = array_map($trim_quotes, explode(',', $enumString));
```

This won't work if you have commas in your enum names though.